# Block Diagram Reduction Error?

Tags: linear-control

I am reducing a block diagram manually and am not sure whether the following step is a valid step? I am using the rule of moving a summing ahead of a block in reverse.

[Reduction Step in Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBuw9.jpg)

I've checked the resulting transfer function before and after this step using MATLAB (connect function and Linear Analysis in Simulink) and they aren't the same, leading me to believe this isn't a valid step.

Any help is greatly appreciated.